# IIS cannot get my environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, iis, environment-variables

I would like to use environment variable in my web application.

I go to the advanced system settings and set my environment variable (for example MY_HOST_NAME) by system-level variables.
Then I restart the server and check with the commandline "set" if the variable is there and I can see it.
But if I try to get the variable within my application which is hosted by IIS, there is the variable null.
The code which I'm using:

```
var host = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_HOST_NAME");
```

Knows anyone where the problem could be or how can I find the bug?

Answer (score 25):

If by restarting server you mean Restart from IIS Manager, then this will not be enough.
In case you don't want to restart the machine (who does?),
you'll have to restart iis from an elevated prompt to pickup the newly changed variables

```
iisreset /restart
```

or in case one prefers some more typing

```
net stop w3svc && net start w3svc
```

Comment: Stopping and starting the "server" via IIS Manager did not seem to be enough. Using `iisreset /restart` did it.

Answer (score 4):

Is it a user environmental variable, or a system-level variable?  The reason I ask is your IIS code is probably running as a different user.  If your variable is a user variable, it wouldn't be present when the code runs as the other user.

Go to the control panel, system properties:

[image]

Comment: it's a system-level variable.